# Operand types are not compatible with the operator in ax 2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

for bellow code i am getting the error like  Operand types are not compatible with the operator. operand types are as followed.

```
str fileName;
int hfile;
hfile = WinAPIServer::createFile(fileName);
```

the code is directly copied from the bellow link.

[Link For The code from Where i Copied it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa609747(v=ax.50).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type of `createFile` is `void` so you can't assign the 'return value' of it to any variable. Consequently the code shown on that site either is wrong or their method signature of `createFile` is different to ours

Comment: Thank yo DAXaholic. Got the point and  problem is rectified by removing the return variable.

Comment: Nice to hear! Please accept the answer in this case